# How can I use atom to format code just like in vscode?

Tags: atom-editor, code-editor

In vscode, I can format cpp code just use Alt-Shift-F or Ctrl-Shift-I (btw., I have installed plugin C/C++).
And that style is my favourite. :)

Before:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    cout<<"Hello world"<<endl;
}
```

After I format it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

Now I love atom, but I wonder how can I do that in Atom.
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried this package? https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify

Comment: But I cannot configure this...., so it doesn't work. Can you give me an uncrustify.cfg can format just like vscode? @Mr-P

Comment: of course I cannot :) you will have to figure this out on your own.. here is one good example -> https://gist.github.com/yeahdongcn/5898005 ... this was the first result I got when googling "uncrustify config file" ...